# Trying to identify this cable name. Hard drive cable

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata, cable

Trying to identify this cable connector name. Specifically, the part that is circled. I know what the whole cable is called, but I am trying to buy some circuit board and I want to search "Circuit board with a {Whatever you call it} port and a USB port." So I need to know what that part specifically is called.

The whole cable is a SATA Hard Drive Cable. This particular design is associated with HP computers and probably others. 
[image: Image of cable.]

Comment: The name of this cable is "custom cable assembly" for HP xxxx line of computers, "spare part number" something like "430883-001" (as an example only).